# Why is the deferred's 'then' callback triggered before nested AJAX's success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm new to jQuery promises, and I'm having trouble successfully doing what I *think* is possible. I have a single AJAX request passed into a `when`. Inside the success callback of that request, I make a *second* AJAX request and assign the returned promise to a variable that I pass to a `when` that I return from the success callback. [Here is a fiddle of the below code.](https://jsfiddle.net/0hdonu6e/1/)

```
Item = function(data) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.price = data.price;
    this.cost = data.cost;
}

$(function() {

  var rec = new Item({
    name: '',
    price: 0,
    cost: 0
  });

    $.when($.ajax({
      url: '/echo/json',
      //url: '/error',
      success: function() {

        rec.name = 'Item1';

        // Get price
        var p1 = $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json',
          success: function() {
            rec.price = 999.99; // I expect to see the price rendered as 999.99
          }
        });

        return $.when(p1);

      },
      error: function() {

        rec.name = 'NULL';

      }
    })
  ).then(function() {
        $('#resultText').css('color', 'green').append('ITEM UPDATE SUCCESS');
        $('#name').text(rec.name);
        $('#price').text(rec.price);
      $('#cost').text(rec.cost);
  }, function() {
        $('#resultText').css('color', 'red').append('ITEM UPDATE FAILURE');
        $('#price').text(rec.price);
      $('#cost').text(rec.cost);
  });
})
```

When you run the fiddle, I don't understand why the rendered "price" isn't 999.99. Why is `p1` resolving before the success callback runs? What needs to change to make it meet my expectations?

Comment: The outer promise doesn't care about the return value of the `success` callback, and so it completes and moves onto its `when` without caring that a second request has been made. You should attach an additional `then` event onto the second AJAX call.

Comment: There is no need for `$.when` in your code. You should remove every single instance of `$.when`.

Comment: FYI, [here's how to do working ajax in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hdonu6e/13/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your promise chain is a mess, and your intent is far from clear, so here's an example, loosely based on your code, to demonstrate how you might make things a little easier to understand.

```
$.ajax({url: '/echo/json'}) //do one request
    .then(function(resultFromServer){
            //yay! 1st request was successful
            return $.ajax({url: '/echo/json'}); //then do another request
        },function(err){
            //something went wrong with the AJAX

            //rethrow to let the next "catch" pick this up, skipping further "then" clauses
            throw err;
        })
    .then(function(resultFromServer) {
            rec.price=999.99; //yay! success again
            //...
        },function() {
            //something went wrong
        });
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I was confusing myself. I also had a bit more complex situation in mind that I didn't initially build into my fiddle...I've updated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/0hdonu6e/7/ and it seems to be doing what I expect. Thanks for the help.